# Beside kwin, what main parts of the Plasma DE can be separately installed on a different desktop (LXQt, etc)?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, kde, panel, plasma-5

I like KDE/Plasma but on an older laptop the `plasmashell` process gets sometimes abruptly high and the desktop becomes unresponsive for some time, especially during internet browsing, but not exclusively. So, I prefer Xfce on that machine, but I would like to try other combinations.

I know `kwin` can be installed as an window manager on other desktops (e.g.LXQt), and I am curious whether other main components of the Plasma experience could run separately from the Plasma desktop.

For example - can the KDE **panel** be installed without `plasmashell`?

Comment: Lots of the Plasma desktop is integrated (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/kde-plasma-desktop) and isn't designed to be used separately.  Some parts (`kwin`, `sddm`) are optional but I don't believe the panel can (ie. it's part of Plasma desktop).  I'm no expert though on KDE/Plasma stack...  (*Lubuntu would love to use components of the panel, but don't want to pull in all or most of plasma and lose the 'light'* we do strive for)

Comment: To add to guiverc's comment, `KDE Applications`, `Plasma`, and `KDE Frameworks` make up the DE. Of these, I think it's only `KDE Applications` that can be run separately. See https://kde.org/applications/.

Comment: @DKBose - on which of those is the kde panel dependent? Beside kwin I like the kde panel for its good multimedia support (especially bluetooth etc, the best on linux afaik)

Comment: Unlike lxpanel, lxqt-panel, tint2 or xfce4-panel, AFAICT, KDE's panel isn't available as a standalone package. I can't find a canonical link but it's probably a component of plasma-desktop itself as guiverc has indicated. An analogous situation probably exists with the GNOME panel.

Comment: According to [this blog](https://blogs.kde.org/2017/03/01/plasma-510-folder-view-default-desktop-mode), "things like the desktop and panels themselves are plugins as well" so I'm guessing that the plasma panel isn't a standalone entity.